# Opensso with SSL Configuration issue in F5 Load Balancers

Tags: saml-2.0, opensso

We are having a web application architecture where our application EAR is deployed in appServer configured with non-ssl Http Port Listener. Every request is routing via F5 Load Balancer-> Web Server-> App Server.

In Load Balancer, we have set an iRule where every Http Request is forwarded to Https set on port 443 and our application is working fine. Now we are trying to implement a SSO using OpenSSO federation solution and SAML Technology. we have deployed the opensso with the  non-ssl http listener configuration in our app server.

now when we try to access the opensso using the url xhttp://domain_name/opensso(dummy protocol), it is redirected as per iRule set on the Load Balancer as xhttps://domain_name/opensso. But in the appearing configuration page of opensso, the server URL is populated as xhttp://domain_name only instead of xhttps://domain_name. Likewise, the same approach is followed to populate all  the URL properties throughout the opensso configuration. So when I tried to generate the metadata using ssoadm GUI, In the form action attribute the url is formed as 'http' and the request method is passed as 'POST' only as per Opensso convention. But when it is redirected to 'https' as per the Load Balancer Rule the Request method is passed as 'GET' instead of post  and the opensso validation fails and throwing the error as 'HTTP Post Protocol is required.

So the issue here is, By default the opensso URL properties should be populated with "https" instead of "http". I would like to know what is the wrong configuration done here. how we could resolve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will find that the answer actually lies within your application server, not the application itself. You need to indicate to the servlet that it is being proxied, and that it is responsible for creating URLs with the HTTPS scheme, not HTTP.

If you're using Tomcat or a derivative, you can modify the server.xml to include the following:

```
 proxyPort="443"
 proxyName="www.domain_name.com"
 scheme="https"
 secure="true"
```

Comment: Is any SSL Certificates to be installed in App/Web Server to the above configuration work? As of now we have installed the SSL Certificates in Load Balancer alone.

Comment: It doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the load balancer to redirect to https with a 307 http status code which informs the client to use the original request method.  If POST was the original request method then following the redirect the client will continue to use POST instead of a GET.

HTTP::respond 307 Location "https://[HTTP::host][HTTP::uri]"